# Python: Creating one chart from same position in multiple dataframes

Tags: python, charts

I have 3 dataframes, each with columns A, B, C, and D. One dataframe contains the values, the second contains a rolling mean, and the third contains the rolling standard deviation:

```
#data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
#rolling mean
df_mu = df.rolling(window=100).mean()
#rolling standard deviation
df_sd = df.rolling(window=100).std()
```

I would like to create one chart that has 3 series: A, A's rolling mean, A's rolling STD. Essentially, in one chart, I want to see df.A, df_mu.A, df_sd.A

I would like to then repeat the process for B, C, and D.

The result is 4 charts, with 3 series in each chart. I would like these charts to be displayed within the iPython notebook.

Does anyone know how I can do this efficiently? Thank you.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
#data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
#rolling mean
df_mu = df.rolling(window=100).mean()
#rolling standard deviation
df_sd = df.rolling(window=100).std()

for col in df.columns:
    plt.plot(df.index.values, df[col], 'r--', df_mu[col], 'b--', df_sd[col], 'g--')
    plt.title(col)
    plt.savefig('C:/Users/test/Google Drive/Working Folder')
    plt.close()
```

I have tried but it doesn't plot in my ipython notebook nor does it save anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What aspect of a column do you want to plot in a chart? I mean they are in different shape than the associated mean and std column

Comment: Thanks Ali. Including the NA's, they are the same length. Mu and SD will start later on the chart, when all data is available, but that's fine. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line chart could be produced by the following few lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for col in df.columns:
    plt.plot(df.index.values, df[col], 'r--', df_mu[col], 'b--', df_sd[col], 'g--')
    plt.title(col)
    plt.savefig('/path/to/store/plots')
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I complete this in the python notebook?

Comment: You can add the above code snippet to your code and should work assuming that you are using the same names for the dataframes, does that help?

Comment: Thank you Ali. It doesn't work for me. The plots don't plot and the files don't save.

Comment: Do you set the path correctly? what error do you get?

Comment: Thank you Ali. Yes I did. I only get one chart, named ".png"

Comment: You need to somehow include the column name in the file name, like: `plt.savefig('/path/to/store/plots/{}.png'.format(col))`

Comment: Thank you Ali! That saves the pictures nicely! Appreciate it.  What do you think I need to do to also show the plot in the notebook?

Comment: Sure, you need to add `#%matplotlib inline` to the begining of your notebook and then replace `plt.savefig(...)` with `plt.show()`, if the answer resolves your issue, please mark it as accepted solution, thanks.